# Resizing an Image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to create a function the scales an image based on a value (scale_zoom) for a homework assignment. I don't want to use the MATLAB built in function `resize()` in this function so I'm trying to interpolate. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is what I have so far:

```
function pic_new=scale_image(pic,scale_zoom)
    [row, col]=size(pic)
    ht_scale=size(pic,1)/scale_zoom*col
    wid_scale=size(pic,2)/scale_zoom*row

    size(ht_scale)
    size(wid_scale)
    x=(0:scale_zoom)*wid_scale
    y=(0:scale_zoom)*ht_scale
    length(x)
    length(y)
    %plotvals=0:0.1:scale_zoom (this is not necessary i think)
    newimg=interp1(pic,x,y,'cubic')
    image(newimg)
end
```

I think I'm interpolating it very incorrectly :/

Comment: I assume you mean that you don't want to use `imresize`, even though you wrote `resize`.  Because I'd use `imresize` for this.

Answer (score 7):

I had [previously answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550878/nearest-neighbor-interpolation-algorithm-in-matlab/1551208#1551208) a question about [scaling images using nearest-neighbor interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1550878/52738), and much of the code and explanations I used there apply here. The main difference is the final interpolation step. Here's how you can write your function, using [INTERP2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/interp2.html) and generalizing for a [2-D grayscale or 3-D RGB image of any type](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html):

```
function pic_new = scale_image(pic,scale_zoom)

  oldSize = size(pic);                               %# Old image size
  newSize = max(floor(scale_zoom.*oldSize(1:2)),1);  %# New image size
  newX = ((1:newSize(2))-0.5)./scale_zoom+0.5;  %# New image pixel X coordinates
  newY = ((1:newSize(1))-0.5)./scale_zoom+0.5;  %# New image pixel Y coordinates
  oldClass = class(pic);  %# Original image type
  pic = double(pic);      %# Convert image to double precision for interpolation

  if numel(oldSize) == 2  %# Interpolate grayscale image

    pic_new = interp2(pic,newX,newY(:),'cubic');

  else                    %# Interpolate RGB image

    pic_new = zeros([newSize 3]);  %# Initialize new image
    pic_new(:,:,1) = interp2(pic(:,:,1),newX,newY(:),'cubic');  %# Red plane
    pic_new(:,:,2) = interp2(pic(:,:,2),newX,newY(:),'cubic');  %# Green plane
    pic_new(:,:,3) = interp2(pic(:,:,3),newX,newY(:),'cubic');  %# Blue plane

  end

  pic_new = cast(pic_new,oldClass);  %# Convert back to original image type

end
```

And you can test it as follows:

```
img = imread('peppers.png');      %# Load the sample peppers image
newImage = scale_image(img,0.3);  %# Scale it to 30%
```