# Matlab - Scale down an image using an average of four pixels

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, rgb, image-scaling

I have just started learning image-processing and Matlab and I'm trying to scale down an image using an average of 4 pixels. That means that for every 4 original pixels I calculate the average and produce 1 output pixel. 
So far I have the following code:

```
img = imread('bird.jpg');
row_size = size(img, 1);
col_size = size(img, 2);
res = zeros(floor(row_size/2), floor(col_size/2));
figure, imshow(img);
for i = 1:2:row_size
    for j = 1:2:col_size
        num = mean([img(i, j), img(i, j+1), img(i+1, j), img(i+1, j+1)]);
        res(round(i/2), round(j/2)) = num;
    end
end
figure, imshow(uint8(res));
```

This code manages to scale down the image but it converts it to grayscale. 
I understand that I probably have to calculate the average of the **RGB** components for the output pixel but I don't know how to access them, calculate the average and insert them to the result matrix.

Comment: Have a look in the work-space and see the variable img. It should be at least a NxMx3 matrix where N and M are the dimensions of the image. You can access to every element as ever for every matrix in Matlab. Try to use the command "who" and "whos" as well

Comment: Can you please write what you obtain if you do A=size(img)? which values inside A?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resizing an Image in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183155/resizing-an-image-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take care of that using the modified code below:

```
img = imread('bird.jpg');
row_size = size(img, 1);
col_size = size(img, 2);
figure, imshow(img);

res = zeros(floor(row_size/2), floor(col_size/2), 3); %Pre-allocation
for p = 1:2:row_size
    for q = 1:2:col_size
        num = mean([img(p, q,:), img(p, q+1,:), img(p+1, q,:), img(p+1, q+1,:)]);
        res(round(p/2), round(q/2),:) = num;
    end
end
figure, imshow(uint8(res));
```

I took a sample image of `1200x1600x3 uint8` which is converted to `600x800x3 uint8` by the above code which is correct because `(1200*1600)/4 = 480000` and `600*800 = 480000`

**P.S :**  I changed the variable names `i` and `j` to `p` and `q` respectively since `i` and `j` are reserved for [**`imaginary numbers`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: You can skip the third for loop by using `:` i mean using            `' num = mean([img(p, q,:), img(p, q+1,:, img(p+1, q,:), img(p+1, q+1,:)]);
            res(round(p/2), round(q/2),:) = num; `

Comment: Thanks @itzikBenShabat !

Comment: @itzikBenShabat your approach gave me this error "Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts. In the line res(round(i/2), round(j/2), :) = num;". Do you know why?

Comment: @formap Are you using exactly the same code as in my answer?

Comment: I had made a typo. Sorry about that. Thank you to you both! @itzikBenShabat

Answer (score 4):

In Matlab, an RGB image is treated as a 3D array. You can check it with:

```
depth_size = size(img, 3)

depth_size =

     3
```

The loop solution, as you have done, is explained in [Sardar_Usama's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39976574/6469393). However, in Matlab it is recommended to avoid loops whenever you want to gain speed.

This is a vectorized solution to scale down an RGB image by a factor of `n`:

```
img = imread('bird.jpg');
n = 2; % n can only be integer
[row_size, col_size] = size(img(:, :, 1));

% getting rid of extra rows and columns that won't be counted in averaging:
I = img(1:n*floor(row_size / n), 1:n*floor(col_size / n), :);
[r, ~] = size(I(:, :, 1));

% separating and re-ordering the three colors of image in a way ...
% that averaging could be done with a single 'mean' command:
R = reshape(permute(reshape(I(:, :, 1), r, n, []), [2, 1, 3]), n*n, [], 1);
G = reshape(permute(reshape(I(:, :, 2), r, n, []), [2, 1, 3]), n*n, [], 1);
B = reshape(permute(reshape(I(:, :, 3), r, n, []), [2, 1, 3]), n*n, [], 1);

% averaging and reshaping the colors back to the image form:
R_avg = reshape(mean(R), r / n, []);
G_avg = reshape(mean(G), r / n, []);
B_avg = reshape(mean(B), r / n, []);

% concatenating the three colors together:
scaled_img = cat(3, R_avg, G_avg, B_avg); 

% casting the result to the class of original image
scaled_img = cast(scaled_img, 'like', img);
```

#### Benchmarking:

If you want to know why vectorized solutions are more popular, take a look at how long it takes to process an RGB 768 x 1024 image with the two methods:

```
------------------- With vectorized solution:
Elapsed time is 0.024690 seconds.

------------------- With nested loop solution:
Elapsed time is 6.127933 seconds.
```

So there is more than 2 orders of magnitude difference of speed between the two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution can be using the function `blockproc` as mentioned at  [this link](http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/matlab/blockaverage). This will also avoid for loops.