# Image interpolation in MATLAB involves interp1

Tags: matlab, interpolation, image-resizing

currently I'm struggling to create a solution to resize an image(colour and greyscale) using interp1() in MATLAB. I've looked everywhere but the only solution I found is to use interp2() which is something I can't. I have been trying and researching for almost 3 days now, but nothing help. thank you in advance.

Comment: Why you can't _interp2_ ?

Comment: I understand that it is easier for me to use interp2 but in this question, i can only use interp1.

Comment: I have been looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183155/resizing-an-image-in-matlab) and trying to refer to it but something is still wrong or missing.

Comment: If you have a RGB image read as I, you can try using: I = I(1:2:end,1:2:end,3) etc.....

Comment: @SivaSrinivasKolukula yes I have to work with both RGB and greyscale but I still don't understand what you mean. Can u explain that further? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are strict on using interp1..you may proceed as follows. Do interpolation based on global indices.

```
I = imread('peppers.png') ;
[nx,ny,t] = size(I) ;
%%
dx = 4 ; dy = 4 ;   % see to it that dx and dy are multiples of nx and ny
%% Global indices 
idx = 1:nx*ny ;
% for interpolation 
idxi = 1:dx:nx ; idyi = 1:dy:ny ;
[I1,J1] = meshgrid(idxi,idyi) ;
idxi = sub2ind([nx,ny],I1,J1)' ;
%%
nxi = nx/dx ; nyi = ny/dy ;
I1 = zeros(nxi,nyi,t) ;
%%
for i = 1:t
    C = I(:,:,i) ;
    temp = interp1(idx,double(C(:)),idxi(:)) ;
    I1(:,:,i) = reshape(temp,nxi,nyi) ;
end
I1 = uint8(I1) ;
imshow(I1)
size(I)
size(I1)
```

Comment: thank you so much @siva props to you man :) i will look into this.

Comment: what if i want to increase the size of the image?

Answer (score 0):

YOu may skip few rows and columns, if you are against interpolation.

```
I = imread('peppers.png') ;   
size(I)
I1 = I(1:2:end,1:2:end,:) ;
size(I1)
```

And also, you can have a look into *imresize*.

```
I2 = imresize(I,[200 200]) ;
```

Comment: I must use interp1() in this problem and imresize() must not be used in this case. thanks in advance.